# soapUI: How to set lists as property

Tags: groovy, soapui

I want to do the following in soapUI using Groovy:

1. Select random value and correspondating data from database
2. Get the response from webservice
3. Compare my database data with the response from the webservice

To achieve this I have the following steps definied:

1. Created property object for the test suite
2. Groovy Script to get the random and correspondating values from database
3. Transformation to put the random value into the request
4. Webservice call to get response
5. Groovy Script to compare the values from my database with the response of the webservice

I did the same steps for other tests already by putting the values from database into the property object in step 2 and reading them from there in step 5. But up to now the values were always normal `String` or `int`. In the response I get in my current test case I get a list back. So I create an array and filled it with bean objects my wanted data in step 2. In step 5 I parse my XML-String and convert the data into an Object-Array too. So I can compare all attributes of them.

I wrote the whole test case in a singular script and tested it on groovy console first. When I started to transform it to soapUI and working with the property to "transport" the data from step 2 to step 5 my problem occurs as it looks like I can't put an Arraylist to the properties (see error message below).

Now I'm confused that this is not possible as I can easily put SQL-Instances in the properties:

```
def contextSqlInstanz = Sql.newInstance(urlH2, userH2, passwordH2, driverH2)
context.setProperty( "contextSqlInstanz", contextSqlInstanz )

sql = context.getProperty("contextSqlInstanz");
```

So how I can transport my Array, filled the Objects, from step 2 to step 5 to compare it with my webservice response. I **DON'T** want to convert both to strings and compare if the strings are equal but I want to compare each attributes of my bean-class by hand.

Bean Class:

```
class myBean {

    String value1;
    String value2;
    ...
}
```

Reading my local database, generating the beans and put them into a list

```
function getdata() {  
  def liste = []

  // sql-statements
  sql.eachRow(...) {

   def myBean = new myBean();

   myBean.value1 = it.value1.toString();
   myBean.value2 =  it.value2.toString();
   ...

   liste.add(Schluesselwert)

  }

  return liste   
}
```

Trying to put the list into properties

```
sollListeH2 = getdata()

def props = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("P_testcase")
props.setPropertyValue( "sollListe", sollListeH2)
```

results in:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlPropertiesTestStep.setPropertyValue() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList) values: [sollListe, [value1@15d4334, value2@1e739c8, ...]] Possible solutions: setPropertyValue(java.lang.String, java.lang.String), getPropertyValue(java.lang.String) error at line: 91

Comment: why would you use list instead of iterating throuh it? You can set property a String value

Comment: Dont understand exactly what you mean. In step 5 I iterate through the list to compare each attribute of each object? Sure I could make Strings for each attribute for each object, but this is a) ugly and b) even with small lists of lets say 5 objects each with 8 attributes this would be 80 propertystrings :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I didn't find another way I did it the ugly way by putting each value as an own property into the propteries

Setting the props in step 2:

```
def convertVectorToProps(vector) {  
  def size = vector.size();

  def props = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("P_testcase")

  props.setPropertyValue("sollSize", size.toString())

  for(int i=0; i < size; i++) { 

     props.setPropertyValue("myBean.value1" + i, vector.value1[i]);
     props.setPropertyValue("myBean.value2" + i, vector.value2[i]);

     ...
  }
}
```

Reading the props in step 5 and build new vector:

```
def convertPropsToVector() {

  def props = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("P_testcase")

  def sollSize = props.getPropertyValue("sollSize").toInteger() 

  SollListe = [];


  for(int i=0; i < sollSize; i++) { 

    def myBean = new myBean();

     myBean.value1 = props.getPropertyValue("myBean.value1" + i);
     myBean.value2 = props.getPropertyValue("myBean.value2" + i);  

     SollListe << myBean
  }

  return SollListe
}
```